# underscore table rows do not maintain css

Tags: javascript, html, css, underscore.js

I'm trying to make a table out of rows generated by underscore templates but whenever I add a template with this command

```
$("#mytable").prepend(_.template($("#tableRow").html(), { thing: this }));
```

all of the css is lost. When I put the row in manually (not with the template) the css functions properly.

Below is my index.html

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App</title>



    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <script src="Scripts/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ViewApp</h1>



    <table id="mytable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <td>ufd</td>
            <td>553</td>
            <td>fgv</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <script type="text/html" id="tableRow">
        <tr>
            <td><%= thing.type %></td>
            <td><%= thing.title %></td>
            <td><%= thing.date %></td>
        </tr>
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks!

Comment: I would examine the generated HTML to ensure it is in the right place.

Comment: @Diodeus ahhhh okay the manually placed one is in tbody and the others arent! Thanks! I changed my html to <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
        <tbody id="mytable"></tbody>
    </table> and it works now!

Comment: You might want to convert that comment to an answer. Some browsers will "clean up" your HTML by adding missing elements (such as `<tbody>`) or correcting what you've given them so that it matches the standard. Looks like that's what you're running into.

Comment: @muistooshort That doesn't depend on the browser, but on the file type. HTML inserts `tbody` elements when not explicitly given in the source; XHTML doesn't. However, it doesn't do this when adding children to the DOM tree with Javascript.

Comment: @Slicedbread If the CSS works with table rows inside tbody, but not outside, it sounds like your CSS is too specific. Does it contain selectors like `table > tbody` or `table > tr` somewhere? Is it possible to change that?

Comment: @MrLister: Why would it matter where the "HTML" comes from? And the first code block shows you how the DOM is being manipulated, there's no child selector involved, I see that particular problem usually occurring when someone reads some XPath out of a browser's version of the DOM and then try to apply that to some library's version of the DOM.

Comment: @muistooshort The "problem" is with the parsing of the source code: the rules say that tables can't contain `tr` elements directly, and that the start tag to `tbody` is optional. So the parser inserts a `tbody` whenever it encounters a `tr` as a child of a `table` in the source. But the Javascript DOM routines don't use the same kind of parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my html to

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed"> 
<tbody id="mytable"></tbody> 
</table>
```

and it works now!